# Android: Delay dropbox upload intentionally

Tags: sync, dropbox

Is might seem an odd question for some.. But I often find myself wishing that dropbox would wait 5-10 minutes before uploading my newly taken photos. The reason is that sometimes I take a blurry picture and delete it straight away - but dropbox alwas snap it before an upload it to my dropbox. So I have to delete it on my dropbox..

I actually think that what I need would be total sync - so deleting on my phone would delete on dropbox. But I feel that this solution would be too risky.. so would just be happy with a delayed upload that just upload what I have in my camera folder.

Any such solution?

Comment: Turn off dropbox sync, and checkout e.g. [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) would be an option (FolderSync also supports Dropbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated already, one solution would be to use an app that lets you synchronize with dropbox.
I personally already used Dropsync. It works flawlessly, however, the free version only lets you sync one main folder. So that was not really an option.

The solution I just came up with is making good use of the Tasker app yet again.

- tell Tasker if the camera or gallery apps are running and mobile data is enabled, disable mobile data.
- then as exit task (to be executed when camera/gallery get closed) re-enable mobile data.

Dropbox will then upload all the shots I did not delete right away using the camera/gallery app.